# jquery mobile page fluctuating on ajax reponce load

Tags: php, ajax, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working with a mobile application in which 
first page has

**Html**

```
    <ul>
    <li>121212</li>
    <li>123233</li>
    <li>232323</li>
    <li>4323423</li>
    <ul>
```

when user click on "li" then he/she entered on next page which will retrieve data related to selected "li" via `Ajax`.
this is almost going good..

But when `Ajax` response come page is fluctuating 2 times.
Means one time page loading, next time page totally white and then again showing page with `Ajax` response.
Why ???

**J query**

```
 $("clickOnLi").click(function(){
        var id= $(this).val(); //get the selected li value
        $('.loadingGif').css({ 'display':'block' });
        $("#ulShowContent").html(''); // to remove old inner HTML to show new result html
        var dataString = 'selectedid='+id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: remoteUrl+"handler.php",
            data : dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response){
                    $('.loadingGif').css({ 'display':'none' });
                    $("#ulShowContent").html(response); 
                }
                }
        });
    })



**and the result will show in this html** 


<ul id="ulShowContent" data-role="listview"> 
    <li class="comment chatsend">
        <div class="comment-meta">
            data 1
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="comment chatsend">
        <div class="comment-meta">
            data 2
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Few question. Do you do an ajax call before a page change or after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change how you deal a page change and **AJAX** call.

What I have understand from your question, after click on **`LI`** element, page change is initialized and **`AJAX`** call is sent to a **`PHP`** server.

You will need to change this logic. Page fluctuations are cause by **`AJAX`** call which is executed during the transition from one page to an another.

This can be fixed like this:

- On a first page remove **`HREF`** attribute from a list element
- Add a click event to every list element
- **`AJAX`** call should be executed on click event, at a same time show your custom loader (or use a default one)
- When server side data is retrieved you need to store it so it can be accessed from an another page. Here you will find my other **[ANSWER](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** where you can find various methods of storing data during page transitions, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**, just search for a chapter called: **Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions** (your best bet is a **`localstorage`**).
- Initialize a page change with **`changePage`** function
- During a **`pagebeforeshow`** event (page is not yet displayed) append new data to the new container
- When second page is finally shown everything will be there and

Comment: Ok sir ji i will try your advise.. and will give you +1 if this problem will solve... this advice is seems too good.

Comment: If you want/need I will send you a basic working demo I used to help someone else.

Comment: Just send me your mail, you will find mine in my profile. I will send you an archived project. This example uses PHP/Mysql server side code but this is not going to be a problem for you.

Comment: mail sent, take a look and tell me if it make sense.